# Save .zip file to BLOB in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to do this:

1. Take this @HTML and save to file `example.txt`
2. `example.txt` save to `.zip` with password
3. `.zip` file convert to blob and stored into table

Do you know how to do it only in T-SQL? Is it possible?

```
DECLARE @HTML varchar(200)

    SET @HTML = '<html>
    <META http-equiv=Content-Language content=pl>
    <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
    <body style="color:black; font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">
    TEST</body></html>'

    SELECT @HTML
```

Using something like this?

```
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @IMG_PATH
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @TIMESTAMP, 2
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
```

OK I created this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server; 

namespace SaveBlobData
{
    class SaveHTML
    {
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
        public static void SaveBlob(out SqlInt32 value, int idZak)
        {
            value = 3 + idZak;
        }
    }
}
```

I add `.dll` but I get error when I select this. Where is problem?

[image]

Comment: Looks like homework :) And... `example.txt` already exists or you must create it via t-sql? And what will be used to create zip-archive 7-zip, winrar...?

Comment: I have to create example.txt from this text in @HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Take This @HTML and save to file example.txt

For this part you can use OLE Automation Object

```
DECLARE @FSO int,
        @oFile int,
        @filename nvarchar(max) = 'c:\Folder\example.txt'

-- Create OLE Automation Object
EXEC sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FSO OUT

-- Create file
EXEC sp_OAMethod @FSO, 'CreateTextFile', @oFile OUT, @filename, 8 , True

-- Write data
EXEC sp_OAMethod @oFile, 'Write', NULL, @HTML

-- Clear used objects
EXEC sp_OADestroy @FSO
EXEC sp_OADestroy @oFile
```

2. example.txt save to .zip with Password

Don't know how this could be done with t-sql, for that purpose we use powershell (or cmd):

```
# path to 7-zip
$zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
# file 
$FilesArh = "c:\Folder\example.zip"
$Dir = "c:\Folder\example.txt"
&$zip a "$FilesArh" "$Dir"
```

Create file `Test1.ps1` with this inside:

```
param
(
[String] $FilesArh,
[String] $Dir
) 
# path to 7-zip
$zip = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
&$zip a "$FilesArh" "$Dir"
```

Launch it from SQL Server:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'powershell C:\Folder\Test.ps1 "c:\Folder\example.zip" "c:\Folder\example.txt"'
```

3. .zip file convert to blob and put to table:

With [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) you can get BLOB data and INSERT it into table.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (BLOB_field)
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\Folder\example.zip', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

Comment: do you know also how to put password to .zip file?

Comment: If using 7-zip then add `-pPASSWORD` like `&$zip a "$FilesArh" "$Dir" -pPASSWORD`. Another options you can read [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this by using CLR Stored Procedure that allows you to access resources being out of SQL Server control. You can write this procedure in .NET (you can do anything you want in this procedure as for example read file, compress it, etc). Then you have to prepare a DLL assembly and connect it with SQL Server. Here you are an example from MSDN how to create a procedure from external assembly:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyFirstUdp FROM 'C:\Programming\MyFirstUdp.dll';
CREATE PROCEDURE HelloWorld
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyFirstUdp.StoredProcedures.HelloWorld;
EXEC HelloWorld;
```

More information about CLR Stored Procedures (and presented example) you can find on https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms131094(v=sql.110).aspx

Until you have your CLR proceure available in SQL Server then you can call it just from the batch.